# Spring security change remember me cookie name

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is it possible via configuration to change the default name of the the remember me cookie ?

By default the cookie name is: `SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE` and I would like to have a less obvious cookie name.

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userService"/>
    <property name="key" value="remember-me-security"/>
    <property name="cookieName" value="remember_me_cookie" />
</bean>
```

Comment: in the <http configuration should I change something ?
I had something like
<http use-expressions='true'>
<remember-me user-service-ref="jdbcUserService"/>
</http>

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Security 4 , the below works .

```
 <remember-me
  key="<yourKey>"
  remember-me-parameter="remember-me"
  token-validity-seconds="1209600"
  user-service-ref="userDetailsService"
  remember-me-cookie="<whateveryouwanttonamethecookie>"
  />
```